# Chaining node-Scripts together and using node-Scripts on multiple files

Tags: json, node.js, bash, shell, command

I´m trying to chain multiple conversion using Node. So for example:

1. Converting multiple files in a folder (JSON to JSON using a node script)
2. Converting the JSON I got from Step 1 to an .xlsx (while keeping the
   name)

Both work fine, but I have to convert multiple files, so I´m trying to find a way to chain both command together into one and then using it on a whole folder. Do I use pipe and xargs here?

The commands I use for both are of the form
node script.js -i INPUT.json -o OUTPUT.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was a simple shell script with 2 loops:

```
for file in /dir/ do;
node convert1.js $file $file.out.json -c config1.js
done

for file in /dir/ do;
node convert2.js $file $file.xlsx -c config2.js
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean in Step 1, however, first of all take a look here: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27287427/convert-json-into-xlsx-file), which seems to address your question.

As to the xslx...try the [NPM icg-json-to-xlsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27287427/convert-json-into-xlsx-file)

If JSON to JSON means take one file convert it to non-nested or nested then not sure but you may interested in this: [json-stable-stringify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-stable-stringify)

Comment: Oh, my bad I formulated the question wrong!I´m conversing json to json to change how the data inside is structured. This works seamlessly. What I´m trying to accomplish is using the script on a whole folder on multiple files. The best case would be if i would be able to pipe the 2 scripts together, so I only have to enter 1 command and i get 2 files.