# how to convert data json to xlsx in node js

Tags: node.js, angular

I need your help. From the nodejs terminal, i want to download an excel file and convert data json   to xlsx
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uK8FS.png)

Comment: i have to convert data json to file xlsx in nodejs

Comment: var XLSX = require('xlsx');

Comment: not working require xlsx  and i install by npm install xlsx  and in browser  xlsx not found

Comment: possible duplicate of  [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27287427/convert-json-into-xlsx-file)

Comment: Please don't post images of code. The images aren't accessible, and if you [edit] the question and paste the code in you can use the button with {} on it to format that as code. Then the text will be searchable.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var arrData = typeof JSONData != 'object' ? JSON.parse(JSONData) : JSONData;
    var xl = '';
    if (ShowLabel) {
        var row = "";
        for (var index in arrData[0]) {
            row += index + ',';
        }
        row = row.slice(0, -1);
        xl += row + '\r\n';
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
        var row = "";
        for (var index in arrData[i]) {
            row += '"' + arrData[i][index] + '",';
        }
        row.slice(0, row.length - 1);
        xl += row + '\r\n';
    }
    if (xl == '') {
        this.alertService.error("Invalid data");
        return;
    }
    var fileName = "file_";
    fileName += ReportTitle.replace(/ /g, "_");
    var uri = 'data:text/xlsx;application/vnd.openxmlformats;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(xl);
    var link = document.createElement("a");
     link.href = uri;
    link.style.cssText = "visibility:hidden";
    link.download = fileName+".xlsx";
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click(); 
    document.body.removeChild(link);
```

Comment: help my to convert data json to xlsx file in node js

Answer (score 0):

help my to convert data  json to xlsx file using node js 
this code in valid in my system linux and not working in windows and mac 
problem extession

```
 var arrData = typeof JSONData != 'object' ? JSON.parse(JSONData) : JSONData;
    var xl = '';
    if (ShowLabel) {
        var row = "";
        for (var index in arrData[0]) {
            row += index + ',';
        }
        row = row.slice(0, -1);
        xl += row + '\r\n';
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
        var row = "";
        for (var index in arrData[i]) {
            row += '"' + arrData[i][index] + '",';
        }
        row.slice(0, row.length - 1);
        xl += row + '\r\n';
    }
    if (xl == '') {
        this.alertService.error("Invalid data");
        return;
    }
    var fileName = "file_";
    fileName += ReportTitle.replace(/ /g, "_");
    var uri = 'data:text/xlsx;application/vnd.openxmlformats;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(xl);
    var link = document.createElement("a");
     link.href = uri;
    link.style.cssText = "visibility:hidden";
    link.download = fileName+".xlsx";
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click(); 
    document.body.removeChild(link);
```