# Convert JSON to XLSX and download it in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, xlsx

I am trying to convert JSON to XLSX in nodejs download that XLSX to the client browser. I used XLSX npm module to convert json to XLSX it is converting the JSON to Workbook, but I cannot download that file.

```
const arr = [
            { name: 'Moran', role: 'back' },
            { name: 'Alain', role: 'front' },
            { name: 'Tony', role: 'back' },
            { name: 'Mike', role: 'back' },
            { name: 'Abo', role: 'back' },
            { name: 'Toni', role: 'back' },
        ]
        const fileName = 'test.xlsx';

        const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(arr);
        const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
        XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'test');
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27287427/convert-json-into-xlsx-file follow these staps, hope it will work.

Comment: @MukeshBurnwalMike Followed those steps exactly but it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get that work
use `npm i node-json-xlsx`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-json-xlsx

Answer (score 1):

you can use also `npm i xlsx`

find more at : https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx

Answer (score 1):

This should be the correct way

```
            const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(theData);
            const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
            XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "Sheet1");
            const filename="myfilename.xlsx";
            XLSX.writeFile(wb, filename);
```